# Adding Target Groups to R2 Data Model

Tags: dxa, tbb, r2, targetgroups

I have a clean instance of **SDL Web 8** with **DXA v2.0** and am using the new **R2 data model**.

I want to expose Target Group Conditions in the JSON generated by the DXA R2 TBBs but I am not having much success.

I have updated the **RenderComponentContent** and **RenderPageContent** TBBs to include the **AddTargetGroupsModelBuilder** model builder as the last item in the **modelBuilderTypeNames** pipeline although based on the source code I think it should only be needed in the **RenderComponentContent** TBB.

See: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/release/2.0/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.R2/Data/TargetGroups/AddTargetGroupsModelBuilder.cs

Despite adding this TBB and checking Target Groups for a given page, I do not see anything in the JSON that represents the serialized data in the output.

Am I missing any obvious steps here? Happy to provide more verbose detail on request.

Comment: Have you tried debugging a Page in Template Builder with Log Level set to Debug? Do you see the message logged by AddTargetGroupModelBuilder?

Comment: Hi @RickPannekoek, I did debug in Template Builder and see the following statements:

AddTargetGroupsModelBuilder: AddTargetGroupsModelBuilder initialized.

DataModelBuilderPipeline: Using Entity Model Builder type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.R2.Data.AddTargetGroupsModelBuilder'.

AddTargetGroupsModelBuilder: Adding target groups to entity model data.

That suggests that the model builder executed but I don't see anything in the generated JSON.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are quite a few paths where the model builder can silently not do anything after logging that message. You may have to attach a debugger to see what happens exactly.

Answer (score 1):

It will only generate tags if you Create a Target Group and then 
Add Target group with a component presentation on the page.

**AddTargetGroupsModelBuilder** should be updated in **RenderPageContent** TBBs

JSON output looks like this:

```
"ExtensionData": {
            "TargetGroupConditions": {
              "$type": "Condition[]",
              "$values": [
                {
                  "$type": "CustomerCharacteristicCondition",
                  "Name": "member",
                  "Operator": 0,
                  "Value": "10",
                  "Negate": false
                }
              ]
            }
          }
```

To read more about this how to create a target group and associate, have a look at the documentation "[Target Groups](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-B4945556-AD9E-4A19-AB65-D0A63E96D28C&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-0E8D14CB-3C94-4B46-9A6A-10E91B208D90.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-B4945556-AD9E-4A19-AB65-D0A63E96D28C&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DTarget%2520Groups&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1530135276622&currentQuery=Target%2520Groups&currentScope=)"

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Velmurugan,

I had created multiple Target Groups and checked them against various component presentations on the page.

I can see this reflected in the Page package item but not the JSON in the package Output item.

Comment: I did use CustomerCharacteristicCondition to test, it works for me, what is the condition did you use to add?

Comment: I was testing with CustomerCharacteristicCondition too. I'm going to have to attach a debugger and build the source locally to properly debug this. I'm confident that my CM setup is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It works!

I don't know what changed. I deleted and re-created the Target Groups, re-published the page, and huzzah - the extension data is present in the json.

Thanks to all those who commented and responded.